# Is there a way to simplify this javascript if-statement?

Tags: javascript

not an expert on js but this if-statement still tickles me because I suspect it can be written in a way more clever fashion:

```
if(event.value == "/")
{
    event.value = "/home";
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What is it about the statement that you don't like?  I mean, as statements go, that's pretty short already.

Comment: I came in here expecting a logic problem... this is a white-space problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could omit the braces:

```
if(event.value == "/") event.value = "/home";
```

Or a conditional:

```
event.value = event.value == "/" ? "/home" : event.value;
```

...but I'm not sure either of those is really "better", and a [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/With) you should just stay away from.

Comment: Fast as always :) So that's basically like PHP I guess. Is there a shorter way to refer to event.value 'within' the brackets? Like: if(event.value == "/") sameval = "/home";

Comment: @soren.qvist - There is, the `with` statement I liked above, but it's evil for a few reasons - and not available in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(event.value == "/"){
   event.value += "home";
}
```

Comment: Nice one, 1 less character to type. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
event.value = (event.value == "/") ? "/home" : event.value;
```

would be about the only other practical option. The if() version is far more readable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much more you can do with it really, other than Nick's suggestions, but here's another way to throw into the mix:

```
event.value += (event.value == "/") ? "home" : "";
```

Another, just for fun:

```
event.value = ((function(v){ return v=="/" ? v+'home' : v }(event.value))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a better way. You could omit the braces if your coding style guide allows you to, but it won't semantically make a difference. 
The shorter `event.value = (event.value == '/')?'/home':event.value;` is not so good, because it makes a useless assignment when the value differs from `'/'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into function to make it look better.

```
function GetValue(s1, s2, s3) {
   return s1 == s2 ? s3 : s1;
}

...

event.value = GetValue(event.value, "/", "/home");
```

IMO it's useful only if you need it more than once.